# Webform Civi Payment fields not showing up

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

I just created a webform with a Civi contribution page enabled. When I save the form to test, the payment options are not showing as part of the form. Do I need to do something other then enabling the contribution section and assigning it a contribution page to get the credit card and billing address fields to show?

Comment: If you enter a number into the amount field, does anything happen?

Comment: On the Civi form if I add a number then the billing/payment info pop up at the bottom. But if I do it on the webform I still do not get the payment fields. I just upgraded my Drupal and webform on Friday to the lastest versions.

Comment: Hmmm, could permissions be affecting it? Are you attempting it from an account (or anonymous) that don't have permissions? Just trying to rule out the easy to fix issues first. :)

Comment: I am logged in and have admin rights, so I don't think it is a permissions issue. Do I need to have a separate paypal module in Drupal or as long as it is set up and works in Civi I should be ok?

Comment: Correct, if your payment processor works correctly in Civi, it *should* work on the Drupal. However, certain processors may not. Do you have PayPal Pro or PayPal Standard? And are you able to complete a transaction in a Civi only contribution page?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you are on 7.x-4.15 of webform_civicrm since you say you just upgraded.  If you switch back to 7.x-4.14, does it work?   If so, it looks like the same issue I logged here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2676752

Comment: Yes we are on version 7.x-4.15. I did an upgrade from 7.x-3 so how do I go about reverting back to .14? Or do they usually fix the bugs in a timely manner? I need to get this form done in the next couple of days, so I am trying to figure out what is the fastest way to fix this.

Comment: Just to chime in, I rolled back to webform_civicrm-7.x-4.14 on my site (Civi 4.6.13), and the payment fields work again.

Comment: @Rachel - it's a manual process: download 7.x-4.14 from here: drupal.org/node/2603480 Find your existing webform_civicrm directory (probably under sites/all/modules), remove it and replace it with the files from the download.

Comment: @Rachel - please mark this answer as "Accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left of this answer, it helps other people with the same problem.

Comment: @Aidan - This answer just solved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the fixes outlined here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18449/930

The payment fields should work in webform version 7.x-4.18 with CiviCRM 4.7.18.